# How to execute a command in VS 2010 package manager consol from WPF project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, project, package-managers

I have tried to find the solution of my problem but in vain.
im new to VS2010 package manager console.

We have started up a project using Pickles to generate a document tree of all our accpetance tests.
To update the acceptance test, i need to enter `pm>Pickle-Features -FeatureDirectory .\Features -OutputDirectory .\Html` manually.
what im after is to add this to my WPF c# solution so everytimee i compile my project, i will also update the document tree.

I have create a test project and added what is suggested in the following post
[Execute a NuGet command from c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047341/execute-a-nuget-command-from-c-sharp-code)
still, i cant get it to work. keep on getting the following message 
`System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException`
however when i run the command in the VS2010 package manager console, the command is working like a charm.

```
private void RunPowershell()
{
    const string command = "Pickle-Features -FeatureDirectory .\\Features -OutputDirectory .\\Html";
    try 
    {
        var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
        powerShell.AddCommand(command);
        powerShell.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        lbl.Content = e.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: follow this : http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/246688

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make that command a [post-build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) event command line on your WPF project.

Comment: First, you must copy .ps1 to root of project and so put `Powershell -File "$(ProjectDir)File.ps1"` on post-build event command line.